# Git push error :RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053. internet connection is ok, tried increasing buffer size

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-push

```
Enumerating objects: 282, done.
Counting objects: 100% (282/282), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (231/231), done.
Writing objects: 100% (282/282), 33.54 MiB | 126.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 282 (delta 52), reused 263 (delta 44)
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have already tried the git config buffer increment command and lfs. Also, my internet connection is good git is working fine in other long projects. the problem is only in this project, I have tried deleting the old repo and making a new one but fails. project size is 85MB and it's a small front-end page, I am using githubpages for this project for serving live, but now this error .. Please give me the solution for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem I tried increasing the buffer size for both http as well as https but it did not work what I finally did was

```
git push --force
```

this worked.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that your operating system returned an error code, in this case, Windows socket error 10053.  The description of that error message is this:

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.

That means that you could be experiencing a timeout or other network problem.  Since you're on Windows, these are often caused by third-party antivirus and firewall programs, which are a common source of Git problems there, as well as network proxies or monitoring software.  You can try completely uninstalling any of these pieces of software and restarting, which may fix the problem, or if you have a network proxy, try running from a different network without it.

You could also try using WSL 2, which often bypasses the standard Windows networking and may avoid a lot of these problems.

Otherwise, this is probably just a garden variety network issue which requires standard troubleshooting steps.  What will not help is [increasing `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo), as you suggested you'd done, because that only works if you have a known broken HTTP setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but if it is a network or any timeout error then how git push is successfully working on my other project directories at the same time while this is showing this error

Comment: If you have a flaky network or a bad proxy, it can be that large amounts of data trigger issues that small amounts don't.  If you have some tool or proxy reading your data, it can  think the data is “bad” (malicious, pornographic, etc.) and drop the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I got over this error by splitting the commit into several parts.
If your commit is very large, this could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue because my commit had big csv files. To solve the problem first I switched my repo to push with ssh, but it didn't solve the issue when trying to upload big files, and git recommended me to use https://git-lfs.github.com/

After migrating my csv files following [git-lfs-migrate](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn?utm_source=gitlfs_site&utm_medium=doc_man_migrate_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs) I was able to push without any issue. I hope this helps, regards.