# Git push command not working but gives error: RPC failed

Tags: git, github

After I enter `git push`, I am getting this error and the files are not uploaded.

Please help me to push my code.

My total code repo is more than 1.3Gb. I used to push the code daily without any problems.

Suddenly, this issue shows up:

```
Enumerating objects: 2486, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2486/2486), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2154/2154), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (2407/2407), 138.79 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 2407 (delta 511), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: It seems an network or Internet connection issue. Check your git server is reachable?

Comment: @MiladDastanZand Yes, i have a strong network connection

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the problem persists:

- clone your existing repository in a new folder
- check with git log that your last push is indeed missing
- try, for testing, to make a *small* commit and push it.

From that same newly cloned repository, try and report your work from the old local repository to the new one, and, [assuming the commit is not too big](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467357/6309), push it again, from that new local clone.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes of this issue is if you let the `pushing` operation in progress and leaving your computer, then the screen gonna `turned off` and this one of the aunknown causes for this issue, to resolve this cause you need to configure your screen to not `turn off` / `sleep` after a short duration of time, configure it on `never` or on a long time duration.

I hope this answer gonna help many users as it helped me after one day of searching and trying to find a fix.